# Identifying a file to be cleaned as part of a scons Builder

Tags: scons

I've been using the AccumulateBuilder as detailed on the scons wiki page and all is good.

However, I would really like to be able to automatically clean the files copied across by this builder.  This is per the comment at the bottom of the page for this builder.

My question is: How do I identify with scons for a file to be cleaned, after it has been generated as part of a target?

I'm quite prepared to contribute any result of my ventures to the main scons effort.  I just couldn't find anything that describes how to mark a (target) file for deletion as part of the clean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the env.Clean() function as detailed here:

http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x3159.html

Comment: Thanks!  Obviously I didn't read the manual as well as I could have.  No problems - an updated AccumulateBuilder is on its way.